# "... is not a template" and "expected initializer before '<'" errors

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to compile parts of the Nurbs++ library and getting a bunch of errors like the following. Why?

```
nurbs_pp/matrix/source/vector.cpp:49:20: error: ‘Vector’ is not a template
nurbs_pp/matrix/source/vector.cpp:49:37: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
```

In vector.h:

```
namespace PLib {

  template <class T> class Vector ;

  template<class T> class Vector : public BasicArray<T>
  {
  public:
    int rows() const //!< a reference to the size of the vector                                                                                                                                                     
      { return this->sze ;}
    Vector() : BasicArray<T>(1) {} //!< Basic constructor                                                                                                                                                           
    Vector(const int r) : BasicArray<T>(r) {}
    Vector(const Vector<T>& v) : BasicArray<T>(v) {}
    Vector(const BasicArray<T>& v) : BasicArray<T>(v)  {}
    Vector(T* ap, const int size) : BasicArray<T>(ap,size) {}
    Vector(BasicList<T>& list) : BasicArray<T>(list) {}

    virtual ~Vector() {}

    Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector<T>& v);
    Vector<T>& operator=(const BasicArray<T>& b);
```

in vector.cpp:

```
namespace PLib {

  template <class T> Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T> &b)
```

Comment: What's in line 49 of nurbs_pp/matrix/source/vector.cpp?

Comment: when you are inside the vector class the T is implied so don't put it after vector

Comment: Obvious question: are you including the header?

Comment: You can't separate implementation files from header files in the case of templates.  Put that function definition inside the template class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being in building. There were two files named vector.h, and qmake didn't like that.